# post_migrate signal - call just once after all migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-signals

In this (very simplified) example, I need to do one thing (call `do_something_after_all_apps_migrated()` ) after all the apps have migrated.

The problem is that `post_migrate` signal is called once for every app.

I have one app: `after_migrations`

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from django.dispatch import receiver


class AfterMigrationsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'after_migrations'

    def ready(self):
        @receiver(post_migrate)
        def _post_migrate(sender,**kwargs):
            app_name = kwargs['app_config'].name
            if app_name == 'after_migrations':
                do_something_after_all_apps_migrated()
```

As you can see this would work but the problem is that it is not guaranteed that my app (`after_migrations`) is the latest app that is migrated. That means the Database structure is not guaranteed.

How can I call `do_something_after_all_apps_migrated()` after everything migrated? It does not have to be a signal.

Answer (score 1):

I had to override `migrate` command and use signals to acheive this:

```py
# app/signals.py

from django import dispatch


migrate_finished = dispatch.Signal()
```

```py
# app/management/commands/migrate.py

from django.core.management.base import no_translations
from django.core.management.commands.migrate import Command as MigrateCommand

from ...signals import migrate_finished


class Command(MigrateCommand):
    @no_translations
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        super().handle(*args, **options)
        migrate_finished.send(self)
```

With this you can listen to the `migrate_finished` signal to trigger your post-migrate code.

You can also check if all migrations are applied before sending the signal or before handling it using this function:

```py
from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor


def is_database_synchronized():
    # The code is from django/core/management/commands/migrate.py
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    connection.prepare_database()
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection)
    targets = executor.loader.graph.leaf_nodes()
    return not executor.migration_plan(targets)
```